# printing hash values in new line using tie

Tags: perl

I have a hash with few keys and each key has 20 values.

```
%test={
a=> 10 14 34 56 ....
b=> 56 67 89 66 ...
..
}

@values= {a,b,..}
```

I want to tie values from this hash to another file as shown below

my input file.txt

```
ID
ID
ID
...
```

expected file.txt

```
ID ,10 ,56
ID ,14, 67
ID ,34, 89
ID ,56, 66
..
```

My code right now ties the all the values to the first line of my file. please help formatting it.

```
my $match = "ID";

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";

for my $line (@lines) {

    while ( $line =~ /^($match.*)/ ) {
        $line = $1 . "," . join ',',@test{@values};
    }
}
untie @lines;
```

right now my output is

```
file.txt
ID ,10 ,14, 34, 56,... 56, 67, 89, 66....
ID 
ID 
ID
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output you expect?

Comment: I just updated my current output. I just want to format it as shown in file.txt

Comment: If the file.txt is your expected output, then please provide the file used as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question...

You have some template file that only contains `ID` at the beginning of (n) lines?

And you want to iterate over each `$key` by `$test->{$key}[$line_count]`?

Something seems fishy(I think you must be leaving something out) here. There's going to be quite a few ways to go wrong with this design...

Anyways, I think this is what you're going for:

```
my $match = "ID";
my $test = { 
    a => [ qw(1 3 5) ],
    b => [ qw(2 4 6) ],
};

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";

my $i = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {
    if( $line =~ /^($match.*)/ ) { 
        my @stuff = (); 
        for my $key ( keys %$test ) { 
            push @stuff, $test->{$key}[$i];
        }   
        $line = $1 . ", " . join(', ', @stuff);
        $i++;
    }   
}
untie @lines;
```

Assuming that this is what you have/want:

```
$ cat file.txt
ID
ID
ID
$ test.pl
$ !cat
cat file.txt
ID, 1, 2
ID, 3, 4
ID, 5, 6
```

Comment: how should I change the code using @values as keys. My keys in hash are in wrong order.

Comment: If `(sort keys %$test )` won't do the trick. All you would have to change is the inner `for` to be `for my $key (@values) {`. You will have to make sure each element in the `array` exists as a `key` in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want

```
my %test = (
   a => [ 10, 14, 34, 56, ... ],
   b => [ 56, 67, 89, 66, ... ],
);

for (0..$#{ $test{a} }) {
   print(join(',', 'ID', $test{a}[$_], $test{b}[$_]), "\n");
}
```

---

You could write to a file instead of STDOUT by creating the file using

```
open(my $fh, '>', 'file.txt')
   or die("Can't create file.txt: $!\n");
```

and then using

```
 print($fh ...);
```

but it's better to let the user redirect the output to the file using `>file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take, although the tie seems superfluous to me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
my %test=(
    a=> [qw(10 14 34 56)],
    b=> [qw(56 67 89 66)]
);
my @values= qw(a b);
my $match = "ID";
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";
my $i = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {
    if ( $line =~ /^($match.*)/ ) {
       $line = $1 . "," . join(',', map { $test{$_}->[$i]} @values );
       $i++;
    }
}
untie @lines;
```

*Output (file.txt):*

```
ID,10,56
ID,14,67
ID,34,89
ID,56,66
```

Comment: it shows a warning-- Can't use string ("16 15 0.15  0.015 0."...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 48, <$fh> line 81. at test.pl line 48

Comment: copy and paste the code above instead of modifying your own code. It sounds like you are doing something wrong at the `%test = (....` part

Comment: But the out put file is like                                                ID 10 14 34 56 56 67 89 66                                                                              ID 10 14 34 56 56 67 89 66                                                              ID 10 14 34 56 56 67 89 66...... rather than what I want. Its printing all the values in all th rows

Comment: sorry there was an error with the map statement, the update should fix it.

Comment: @user2441289, I don't know how the suggested change can fix that error :) I thought I wrote that.